# How to show a percentage of an image using the jquery Show() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-effects

i'm trying to create the same nice effect of and overlayed arrow (ie desktop version of chrome) when you swipe left or right in for a mobile browser.

I use javascript and jQuery and for now i can show the arrow when I swipe. I managed to have the distance of the swipe but i can't find a way to link the two so i only show a portion of the arrow in relation with the distance !

```
$('#arrow').show('slide',{direction: 'right'},1000);
$('#arrow').fadeIn();
$('#arrow').fadeOut();
```

I'm trying to do it also with animate() but i'm still stuck :S

Thanks for the help

Comment: position it absolute and animate top/left or bottom/right

Answer (score 0):

You'll need three values: `start`, `end`, `current`.

In your case, you'll need to determine what is the `start` `end` value.

I would say use the width of your swipe-able area (screen), which would give you `0` and `x` (where `x` is the width of your swipe-able area). You already have `current`, which is the distance between `start` and and where your actual swipe ends (width of swipe, perhaps?).

Once you have those values, you can derive a percentage (between 0 and 1) and apply it to your arrow using @mikakun's suggestion. The arrow graphic will either need to be absolutely positioned in the container or set as a background image of the container. That will give you the effect of only seeing a percentage of the arrow as the container expands to reveal more. A nice effect would be to have a semi-transparent/greyed out duplicate of the full arrow in behind the one you are revealing.